# Help to do something or help do something?

Tags: infinitives, ellipsis

I wrote:

> I will help you **to** acquire Russian.

A native English speaker corrected me saying that '**to**' is unnecessary here. Is it correct to say

> "I will help you acquire Russian"

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Eugenia! Here's a related question at ELU: [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After the verb **Help**, you can have an infinitive form of verb. The infinitive form can be either a *to-infinitive* or a *bare infinitive*. That is actually optional. Mostly in conversation or informal English, the *to* is often left out.

Examples -

1. He helps him (to) learn Russian.
2. Alex helped a blind man (to) cross the road.

**N.B** So a bare infinitive as well as an infinitive with *to* is both acceptable after **help**. But it's observed that in BrE the *to-infinitive* form dominates, though bare infinitive also occurs in BrE. On the other hand in AmE a bare infinitive is preferable. When there is a repetition of *to* (a pattern of *to + help + to + verb*) as in this sentence - *she allowed Pearl to help her to stack up her hair* - a bare infinitive is generally occurs. Another place where bare infinitive is preferred is when there is an intervening noun phrase as in *help people break the cycle of poverty*. Bryan A. Garner writes the better usage is to use bare infinitive after **help**, while Pam Peter says the preference of *to-infinitive* in BrE is because of their conservatism but this practice is changing.

Some pattern with **help** from [Google’s Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams)

For the **help + (to) learn**

[image: ngram showing “help to learn” is more prevalent than “help learn”]

For the **help + (to) do**

[image: ngram showing “help do” is more prevalent in modern times than “help to do”]

For the **help + (to) dig**

[image: ngram showing that “help dig” is more prevalent than “help to dig”]

Comment: Thank you. What does **N.B** mean?

Comment: @WXJ96163, it stands for _nota bene_ (a Latin phrase), and it is used in formal writing to call the reader’s attention to a sentence or passage that accompanies it in the text. Please check [this](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-abbreviation-N-B-mean-and-why-do-people-use-it) for more info.

Answer (score 9):

I've just found out that a native speaker would rather use the bare infinitive than the to+infinitive form. I was even taught that bringing in the infinitive (with "to") in the sentence is grammatically wrong, but Google proved *me* wrong.

Help+object+**bare** infinitive (i.e.: basic form of the verb without "to")

> I *helped* the tourists **find** the restaurant they sought.
>
> Graham *helped* the old dude **walk up** the stairs.
>
> Will she be able to *help* **maintain** the peace?

Answer (score 8):

The construction was "to help to do", But to help is used so often with an infinitive that speakers began to consider it something like a modal verb such as can, may etc and began dropping "to".

"to help" isn't yet a modal verb but the drop of "to" might be a first step to changing the status of this verb. Have a look at "need". It can be used as a full verb and as a modal verb.

Today it is almost normal to use "to help" with bare infinitive. But it wouldn't be wrong if you used the to-infinitive.