# What is "intervening noun phrase"?

Tags: meaning, terminology

intervening noun phrase

An ELL [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47223/109190) says

> Another place where bare infinitive is preferred is when there is an **intervening noun phrase** as in help people break the cycle of poverty.

I guess "break the cycle of poverty" is the "intervening noun phrase".

So, what is "intervening noun phrase"?

I searched on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22intervening%20noun%20phrase%22) and got 6 hits, none gives a clear explanation about the concept itself.

I also searched on google, Cambridge Dictionary, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The "intervening noun phrase" is *people*.

"Intervening noun phrase" is not an established grammatical term. The writer is using it literally: a noun phrase which comes between (the "help" and the infinitive).

Comment: People is a phrase, can't believe it. I mean, I believe you. Thank you. If I call it "Intervening noun", every one can still get what I refer to, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163: the point is that it could have been any noun phrase: this one happens to consist of a single noun, but the structure is not limited to that. It could easily have said _help disadvantaged people break the cycle of poverty_.