# What type of adverbs "still" is?

Tags: grammar

In my another post ([What is "intervening noun phrase"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239435/109190)), I left a comment to an answer

> If I call it (people) "intervening noun", every one can **still** get what I refer to, right?

where I used the adverb **still** though, and lots of people use it in lots of situations, I don't know what type it is.

Cambridge Dictionary categorize "still" as "Time adverbs", [another post](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/types-of-adverb/) classify it as "Connecting/linking adverbs". Neither seems appropriate here.

So, what type of adverbs "still" is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverb came from the Old English adjective *stille*, meaning *not moving*. It is used in so many different contexts that to call it an adverb of time may not always seem helpful. But if you can see how the word's meaning evolved from *'not moving'* to *'unchanged'* to *'as before'* its connection with time becomes clear. Your sentence means, roughly, "Everyone can, *as they could before*, get what I refer to."

You might like to study the first four subheadings [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/still). All those examples are of its usage as a 'time adverb'. The other subheadings describe its other usages:
*still* has a great many! When it is used like *consequently* or *besides* to join two clauses, it can be called a 'connecting adverb'.

Comment: Thanks. So, "still" in my example means "as before", therefor, it is a time adverb, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes, that's right.